# Hosting private nuget server issue

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, nuget-server

I have setup my own nuget feed and have hosted that on our dev server.

When I try to push my packages from my local machine to dev machine as below:

```
dotnet nuget push C:\MyProjects\Common.2.0.0.nupkg -k myapi -s https://mydev.com/AENuget/
```

I get the error as:

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed).
```

Now I have read and tried many settings like adding

```
<remove name="WebDAV" /> <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
```

Giving permissions to my nuget packages folder, adding app pool account but still I am not able to resolve this issue.

Secondly instead of pushing if I just copy my nuget package file to the package folder being hosted in our dev server and then in visual studio I add the new server source I get the below error:

```
[Package Source] The V2 feed at 'http://mydev.com/AENuget/Search()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&searchTerm=''&targetFramework=''&includePrerelease=false&$skip=0&$top=26&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'.
```

So looks like neither the push from nuget nor the copy is working. Looks like some permission issue which I am not able to resolve. 
Would appreciate if someone can provide any inputs to this.

FYI: This works fine if I host this on my local machine.

Comment: What are you using for a NuGet server (your own asp.net app using NuGet.Server)? Can you upload a package to the server on the server?

Comment: i created an nuget server as by the code and then hosted that on my dev server. I am then using nuget to push another package to the nuget server that was created where I receive the above error. If I use this locally this works fine.

Comment: Now after making some changes it now throws error: 404 not found

Comment: Also on my nuget server site, when I click on "click here to view your packages" it also throws same error not found

Comment: Everything you keep mentioning seems to indicate you have problems with your server. I would check the nuget server to ensure everything is working as you expect. A note: if it is too difficult to setup, try just making a shared folder on the server and have all machines point to that folder.

Comment: If I make a shared folder, then how would I add that as a package source in my visual studio

Comment: Check this link out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui#package-sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems you are having seem to indicate you are having issues with the NuGet.Server and the system itself. These can be problems with the firewall, hosting configuration (IIS), or a wide variety of problems.

If you are on a very small team, you might just create a shared folder on a network server (with read/write access for the team). You can add the package source to Visual Studio by following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui#package-sources). The source will be the UNC path to the directory (e.g. `\\servername\path\to\nuget\folder`).

NuGet.Server is a package provided by Microsoft and NuGet. This is used widely so I do not believe you have a problem with the package. If you encounter a specific problem, we may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks this works for now. Ideally I would want the nuget server to be working, will lookout for the issue with that though.

Comment: Obviously the NuGet.Server solution is far more ideal. Just a bit hard to try and diagnose issues when they are so generic. If you have another engineer, you could use a second pair of eyes to try and to figure it out together.